# returning the second highest value in an array - ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, integer

I have a function that takes in a string a returns a second highest value.

for example if the input is "abc123" the returning value is 2.
this is working fine.

however I want to change the function so that if only one or no intergers are found.. i want to return -1.

for example if input = "abc1", return value should = -1
the current returning value for this input is 0.

here is my function

```
def function(input)
  input.split("").map { |x| x.to_i }.sort[-2]
end
```

any help would be great!

Comment: What if the input is `"123abc"` or `"a1b2c3"`? Your requirements regarding _"only one or no intergers"_ aren't clear.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd say that `nil` is a more logical return value for such a function, than `-1`.

Comment: Now, for fun, what if we say that the second-highest number in "abc123" is 23? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `#scan` method to select integers first. If size of integers will be less than two — `[-2]` returns nil, therefore you can use `||` to pass your default value.

```
def function(input)
  input.scan(/\d/).map(&:to_i).sort[-2] || -1
end
```

Comment: Please, add `sort` after `map`.

Comment: you'll want to include a `sort` and possibly a `uniq` (depending on requirements) but that looks pretty good to me

Answer (score 2):

```
def second_largest(str)
  (str.gsub(/\d/).max(2)[1] || -1).to_i
end
```

```
second_largest("ab42de61f") #=>  4
second_largest("ab63f")     #=>  3
second_largest("a6b25f")    #=>  5
second_largest("ab1def")    #=> -1
second_largest("abcdef")    #=> -1
```

If

```
str = "ab42de61f"
```

then

```
enum = str.gsub(/\d/)
  #=> #<Enumerator: "ab42de61f":gsub(/\d/)>
```

as [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) returns an enumerator when it is invoked with one argument and no block. In this form it no longer has anything to do with character replacement. It merely enumerates matches of its argument.

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> ["4", "2", "6", "1"]
```

Continuing,

```
arr = enum.max(2)
  #=> ["6", "4"]
```

When the string contains many digits and only the two largest are needed, the use of [Enumerable#max](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) is clearly more efficient than sorting all digits (O(n) vs O(nlog(n)), where `n` is the number of digits.

Next,

```
s = arr[1] || -1
  #=> "4" || -1 => "4"
```

and lastly

```
s.to_i
  #=> 4
```

Similarly,

```
"ab1def".gsub(/\d/).max(2) #=> ["1"]
"abcdef".gsub(/\d/).max(2) #=> []
```

explains the return values (`-1`) for the last two examples<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1. Note that `-1.to_i #=> -1`.</sup>